# ASP.Net Project Reference Get Removed Automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC project and it reference another class library in the same solution. But when I build the solution, the reference get removed and an exclamation mark (!) starting to show. Even if I add reference again, it get removed and exclamation mark is coming. What can be the cause and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi is it third party dll or native ?

Comment: @LDS They are native dll

Comment: If it is user define check the path of the dll .otherwise clean the project and check the dll is present in the debug folder or not ?

Comment: so your project and dll both are .net frameworks based?